# results for each group

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

UPDATED:

There can be is_active = true after is_active = false, so I need to get the last assigned is_active = true and get the preceding is_active = false record

I have a table with this structure

```
id (not pk but each group is incremental), name, grp, is_active (boolean)
```

with data like this for group 1

```
1, name1, group1, true
2, name2, group1, true
3, name3, group1, false
4, name1, group1, false
5, name2, group1, true
6, name3, group1, false <-- this is the next assigned id as the preceding record has an is_active = true
7, (names will differt, group the same and all false)...
```

... more data in the same table but for group2

```
100, name1, group1, true
101, name2, group1, true
102, name3, group1, true
103, name1, group1, true
104, name2, group1, true
105, name3, group1, false <-- this is the next assigned id as the preceding record has an is_active = true
106, (names will differt, group the same and all false)...
```

I have this but it's not working as I would like it to

```
SELECT grp, COUNT(*)
FROM tbl_1
WHERE is_active = false
AND id > (
    SELECT id
    FROM tbl_1
    WHERE is_active = true
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
GROUP BY grp
```

So the return I would like is:

```
group1, 6
group2, 105
```

but I get only

```
group2, 105
```

Comment: Sorry I have updated the question, I will give an upvote for all who answered the previous question correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only really need to find the first `id` where `is_active = false`. It is not necessary to apply "greater than first active" condition on `id`.

```
SELECT MIN(id), grp
  FROM tbl_1
  WHERE is_active = false
  GROUP BY grp
```

**UPDATE:**

Answer to the updated question:

```
SELECT min(id), grp
  FROM tbl_1 t
  WHERE is_active = false
  AND id > (SELECT max(id) 
              FROM tbl_1 
              WHERE is_active = true 
                AND grp = t.grp)
  GROUP BY grp;
```

Comment: Updated my question, could you take a look again please?

Comment: So basically you want the first `id` where `is_active = false` AND that isn't followed by an `id` that has `is_active = true` ? The "Looking for a query that will return the next id where is_active = false for each group" sentence doesn't seem to fit with your update.

Comment: That's why I have the sub select to get the last is_active = true record id

Comment: hmm that still gives me only one result set and not both

Comment: Really? I have a dummy example here that works well http://www.ideone.com/yrabX :S Do you really have 2 different group names?

Comment: could you change the values of group2 id's to be different than group1 id's? BTW really kool site. Start off group2 at 100. I might need to play with this more +1 for a great tool

Comment: @PhillPafford let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2541/discussion-between-vache-and-phill-pafford)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT grp, MIN(id) FROM tbl_1 WHERE is_active = false GROUP BY grp;
```

Comment: Updated my question, could you take a look again please?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
grp,
MIN(Id)
FROM tbl_1
WHERE is_active = false 
GROUP BY grp
```

Comment: Updated my question, could you take a look again please?